# Type Mismatch in Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have this code to store the values of the selected range in an array.

```
dim lRow, i as Integer
dim rngValues() as Variant

rngValues = thisworkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & lRow)


For i = LBound(rngValues) To UBound(rngValues)
    Debug.Print rngValues(i) ' this lines returns Type Mismatch error.
Next i
```

After doing some modification with the column, I have to paste it back to the column.Can you please help me figure this out?

Comment: `rngValues` is a 2-D array, so `Debug.Print rngValues(i, 1)`

Comment: Are you trying to store the Range values or just the Range itself? When you store/load values in memory (`Dim rngValues As Variant : rngValues = thisworkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & lRow).Value`), it's 2 dimensional - 1st dimension: `LBound(rngValues,1)`, 2nd dimension: `LBound(rngValues,2)`. Rows is 1st dimension, Cols is 2nd.

Comment: @PatricK I'm storing range values :)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the comment. It now works. But do you know how to store its the same format? Column C contains date values, and format is `2017/01/31` and when I store it in array, it becomes `1/31/2017`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to return date values in specific format

As Tim Williams already said, your rngValues array is a 2D one

To have it as a 1D array you can code as follows:

```
dim lRow A Long, i as Long '<--| expliciltly declare each variable and use Long for row index ones since they can exceed Integer capacity
dim rngValues as Variant '<--| declare rngValues as a Variant instead as an array of Variant

rngValues = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & lRow).Value) '<--| transpose the "columned" values to "rowed" ones suitable for a 1D array

For i = LBound(rngValues) To UBound(rngValues)
    Debug.Print Format(rngValues(i),"yyyy/mm/dd")
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But do you know any workaround for my above last comment?

Comment: See edited answer. With Format() function you get s string with a date formatted as you need

Comment: I've added this code paste back the values to the column `Thisworkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & lRow) = Format(Application.Transpose(rngValues), "yyyy/mm/dd")` but it  returns Type Mismatch Error.

Comment: That is not what I wrote in my answer: you have to format each array value individually

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out some way. Can we just store the column values to the array on `yyyy/mm/dd` format and paste it back as `yyyy/mm/dd` ?

Comment: Have you tried pasting values back from array to the source cells? If these latter are date formatted they will keep showing the wanted format

Comment: Yes. it just reformatted.What I've done is store the `Column C` values,  then format `Column C` to String and paste back the array to Column C. The purpose of converting Column C to string is to make the formatting constant i.e `2017/01/31` format in the cell value and `2017/01/31` in the formula bar.

Comment: Never mind with my concern. It's now working :) I just have to store the array as text :)

Comment: Fine. As for the _original_  post issue, if you ended up using my solution you may want to mark my answer as accepted. Thank you